# How to set UITableView height according to its content height?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a question about `UITableView`.
I want to let the tableView height according to my cells content height.
So, I use the following code successfully.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    var frame = self.tableView.frame
    frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    self.tableView.frame = frame
}
```

But when I have much data to show, my contents will out of screen.
And the tableView also out of screen. 
Have any ideas to set it's constrain and don't make it out of screen.
I want to set 15 between the tableView bottom layout and superView bottom layout.
I use SnapKit to set autolayout.

```
//I want to set this one is the biggest frame size. Other contents I can scroll the tableView to show the data.

tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in 
    make.top.equalTo(self.topLayoutGuide.snp.bottom)
    make.left.equalTo(10)
    make.right.equalTo(-10)
    make.bottom.equalTo(-15)
}
```

Comment: I had done this but in my case I am reloading a section which makes the glitch in section. So how you getting data? and how you showing? and whther it is changable or not?

Comment: Just in ViewDidLoad get data. And use simple dataSource function "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAt". I don't use reloadData.

Comment: tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

Comment: Can you show me your full code so that I can clearly know what is your requirement?

Comment: I don't undestand what you want here?

Answer (score 5):

You could create a custom `UITableView` :

```
class AutomaticHeightTableView: UITableView {

  override var contentSize: CGSize {
    didSet {
      self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height + 20)
  }

}
```

And then set your `UITableView` Class to `AutomaticHeightTableView`.

This solution is inspired from an answer found on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem using the following method. You only need few lines of code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
}

private func setupTableView() {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Simply set an estimated row height for the UITableView and then set the rowHeight as UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can limit the height of the table's frame, making sure is not longer than its superView, something like this modifying your code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let superViewHeight = self.tableView.superView?.bounds.maxY {
        let maxHeight = superViewHeight - self.tableView.frame.minY
        var frame = self.tableView.frame
        frame.size.height = min(self.tableView.contentSize.height, maxHeight)
        self.tableView.frame = frame
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Work :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! // tableView Height Constraint
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var tblMaxHeight : CGFloat = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let navHeight = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

        tblMaxHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - 40 - navHeight

    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){

        tblHeightConstraint.constant = min(tblMaxHeight, tblView.contentSize.height)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 24
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Row: #\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell!
    }


}
```

**Constraints to tableView :**

[image]

**Output :**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your UITableView inside a UIScrollView and add constraints like this:

**Constraints to Table View**

[image]

Create an IBOutlet of the height constraint and then override *viewWillLayoutSubviews* in your UIViewController

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
self.tableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622457-invalidateintrinsiccontentsize

Comment: sorry, add this code in where? I also add this code below the "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension" and not working.